# Trouble with elementary equation using variables in Java

Tags: java

new programmer here

I am currently trying to to have a little fun of Friday night and whip up a quick calculator to  show fantasy football scores and it won't work

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Players {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt user to enter how many catches
    System.out.print("How many catches did the player have? ");
    int catches = input.nextInt();


    //Prompts user to enter how many receiving yards
    System.out.print("How many yards receiving did the player have? ");
    int recYards = input.nextInt();

    //Prompts user to enter how many rushing yards
    System.out.print("How many yards rushing did the player have? ");
    int rushYards = input.nextInt();


    //Prompts user to enter how many touchdowns  
    System.out.print("How many touchdowns did the player have? ");
    int touchDowns = input.nextInt();


    **//Calculates score
    int points = (catches + (recYards % 10) + (rushYards % 10) + (touchDowns * 6));**  


    // Shows score 
    System.out.print("Your score is " + points );

    }

}
```

I have bolded the problem section in question.

For instance, it gives me scores like this

How many catches did the player have? 10 *(This should be 10 points)*
How many yards receiving did the player have? 100 *(This should be 10 points)*
How many yards rushing did the player have? 50 *(This should be 5 points)*
How many touchdowns did the player have? 2 *(This should be 12 points)*
Your score is 22.0 *(This should be 37 points)*

Could somebody help explain what's going wrong here?

Comment: `%` is modulus (remainder), `/` is divide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mixed modulus `%` with divide `/` up. Modulus gives you the remaining portion of the division. So, for example, 12 mod 10 equals 2.

Comment: Thank you, also I have no idea why someone downvoted this comment

Comment: No problem. If this was the correct answer, please mark it as such, so that other users don't answer your question anymore. Kind regards.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is arguably a typo problem, which is reason enough to close the question, and some people just downvote all the answers to simple questions.